# Freeing returned pointer from function after it is malloc'd inside that function causes chip to crash

Tags: c++, pointers, stm32

I have this call inside main

```
char* IDQueueString = getIDQueue();
pc.printf("[%9.6f] IDQueue: %s\r\n", t.read(), IDQueueString);
free(IDQueueString);
```

And getIDQueue(); is

```
char* getIDQueue(void)
{
    char* returnString;
    char idString[6];
    uint8_t pointer = 0;
    uint8_t queueLength = 0;
    returnString = (char*)malloc((uint32_t)(sizeof(char*)*128));
    if(returnString != 0){
        pc.printf("[%9.6f] MALLOC: %p, len: %d | LINE %d\r\n", t.read(), returnString, (int)(sizeof(char*)*128), __LINE__);
        for(uint8_t i = 0; i < ID_QUEUE_LENGTH; i ++){
            if(ReceivedIDs[i].id != -1){
                queueLength++;
                sprintf(idString, "%d", (int)ReceivedIDs[i].id);
                for(uint8_t j = 0; j < strlen(idString); j++){
                    returnString[pointer] = idString[j];
                    pointer++;
                }
                returnString[pointer++] = ',';
                returnString[pointer++] = ' ';
            }
        }
        if(queueLength > 0){
            returnString[pointer-2] = '.';
            returnString[pointer-1] = '\0';
        }
        if(queueLength == 0){
            returnString = (char*)"Empty!";
        }
        return returnString;
    }else{
        free(returnString);
        error("\x1b[31mMALLOC %d!\x1b[0m\r\n", __LINE__);
        return (char*)"MALLOC!";
    }
}
```

When it reaches `free(IDQueueString);` in the binary it does this somewhere down the chain of instructions:

```
0x08009d6c:   ldr     r6, [r1, #8]  // *0x2000a208, *0x20008500
0x08009d6e:   ldr     r0, [r2, #4]  // *0x200080d8, *0x1002db40
0x08009d70:   cmp     r2, r6        // *0x1002db40, *0x2000a208
```

But it hangs at `0x08009d6e` (or rather returns to a WIRQ loop that loops on itself with

```
0x08004ffc:   b.n     0x8004ffc
```

I'm wondering what causes it to do this?
It's clearly `free();` causing a problem but I can't figure out what's the issue. The value at `r1` and `r2` is `0x00000000` and `r0` is `0x00000009` and `r6` is `0x5DECC885`.

Addresses `0x20000001-0x2001BFFF (112KB)` is the range for SRAM1 and `0x2001C000-0x2001FFFF (16KB)` is the range for SRAM2.

I have no idea what that value `0x5DECC885` is about but it is possibly something to do with the USB-OCD interface.

I'm assuming the way I've used free is incorrect but since I return a pointer to a `malloc();` why can't I free the returned pointer the way I am trying to?

Comment: In two cases, you're returning a pointer that doesn't come from `malloc`.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Unless you're specifically asking about differences between them, don't tag both.

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ, this question use method so this is c++.

Comment: You want to return `NULL` in case something went wrong and not a pointer to an (un`free()`able!) string literal. Like you do here: `return (char*)"MALLOC!";`

Comment: Well to be fair I'm not doing anything with the `return  (char*)"MALLOC!";`, it's just there for completeness. It hangs after the very first call which returns the string succesfully, but then hangs on `free(IDQueueString)`

Comment: By the way, this is very bad cast because you remove the read only attribute of `char const *`.

Comment: Why does it matter, I only added that in the code for my question, it actually returns NULL in my code and should never actually reach that address because I only use 5248 bits of ram out of 128KB

Comment: @Supernovah You also have a code path that does `returnString = (char*)"Empty!";`. I suggest you use a debugger to find your bug(s).

Comment: How am I not returning a pointer, can you potentially tell me what it's actually returning because it sure looks like a pointer `returnString` to me...

Comment: Oh interesting, I had a pretty fundamental misunderstanding of casting to `(char*)` then. What is a minimal way for doing the "Empty!" line? I have it as a series of `returnString[queueLength++] = 'E';` ... `returnString[queueLength++] = '\0';` and that seems pretty cumbersome in terms of number of lines of code...

Comment: Also why did people vote my question down lol?

Comment: Doing `strcpy(returnString, "Empty");` will copy the string literal to the `char` array you allocated. That will fix a single problem, you probably still need to take a careful look at the rest of your code.

Comment: people vote your question down maybe because you don't provide a code that can reproduce you problem, best to have [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Blastfurnace What's wrong with the rest of it sorry? And yea, I'm tired on a Saturday night, guess that was the obvious answer :)

Comment: @Supernovah I'm just being overly cautious, based on this very small sample you might have similar issues elsewhere.

Comment: It's the only function that returns a pointer. I've monitor  memory and it remains static when external inputs are removed. It's in an electronics environment. I've been able to predictably increase bit usage by stimulating the appropriate channels. Also I followed the entire program around through assembly and this was the only issue I encountered.

Why people have downvoted and voted to close my question? Is it not a valid question? If someone has a misunderstanding of the language they use and make a mistake does that mean their question is worth removing? So hostile!

Comment: It has been already noted that you should provide a [mcve], your apparent reluctance to do so is likely the cause of down votes

Comment: The files required to compile for my embedded device number in the thousands. I can't post that here...

Answer (score 1):

You can't free things that didn't come from `malloc` - it is "undefined behaviour" to do so, so depending on how your runtime is designed, what actually happens is "anything is possible", it could hang, crash, start a nuclear war by sending rude messages to Putin signed by Trump, or be "just fine".

There are two solutions for your particular scenario:

If `malloc` fails, return `NULL` (or preferrably `nullptr` if we're in C++). If the queue is empty, return a `malloc`'d string that contains the string "Empty!" (by assigning it with `strcpy` or similar).

Alternatively, and this only works if you KNOW that the queue won't contain words like `"Empty!"` or `"MALLOC!"`: before you call `free`, check if that it isn't one of those strings (using `if(strcmp("Emtpy!", ...) != 0 && strcmp("MALLOC!", ...) != 0) free(...);`.

This could be made easier by having those strings in a list of known strings, and just return that entry, then you could have a function that checks "is it a known constant string" by comparing the pointer value itself. [In fact, this would also work when there is the same content string in the content you are processing, since the content string will have a different address if it came from your code] - it will also help avoid the problems of "Oh, I changed the value of the returned string, but not the check before free", since it's only one place to change for bot uses.

Comment: The contents of the string are for human readability so their contents and what they match isn't relevant information. They originate from `uint16_t` printed with `%d`. They're capped with either `{ '.', '\0' }` or `{ ',', ' ' }` for formatting. Also it's not really supposed to be c++, I'm just using `pc.printf` in development (virtual serial), I'll remove it come release time.

Comment: I was trying to give a more generic answer - I don't know if you plan on expanding your code to use similar code for some text content later, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I see the disassebly listing I know that it will be something silly. Wrong program logic - but the compiler has to be wrong :)

It is a good to allocate memory which will before the function call. All local mallocs should be freed before the return. It makes it easier to debug the code (especially the memory leaks).

You have a zillion ways to communicate with another part of the program, but the one you have chosen is the worst one. First it is good to separate errors (like failed mallocs) from the application exceptions like empty name in your case. Myself I would make this function to return int (for example negative ones as system errors, zero if OK and  positive for application exceptions) - making dealing with them easier, and pointer to be returned via pointer to pointer. 
But it you want to malloc (and to do not free) in the function -

```
if((resultCode = getIDQueue(& IDQueueString) >= 0)
{
   // do something (you can have another switch here to deal with application exceptions like empty name for example)
   free(IDQueueString);
}
else
{
 switch (resultCode) 
 {
   case -1:
     // do something malloc failed
     break:
   case -2:
     //deal with another error 
     break;
  //...... etc etc 
   default:
     // ----
     break;
 }
}
```